# React 16 Upgrade dependency warnings

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded from React 15.4 to React 16.  I also went through all the js libraries in my package.json and updated them to the latest.  Still i'm getting these warnings and am not sure how to resolve them.

```
npm WARN react-render-html@0.5.2 requires a peer of react@^15.1.0 but none was installed.    
npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none was installed.    
npm WARN recharts@1.0.0-alpha.6 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.    
npm WARN @daptiv/ppm-npmp-react-theme@2.0.5 requires a peer of react@^15.6.1 but none was installed.    
npm WARN react-resize-detector@0.6.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.    
npm WARN react-smooth@0.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.    
npm WARN react-smooth@0.3.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.    
npm WARN ppm-mspa-projectdashboard@0.0.23 No repository field.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't resolve these warnings, the authors of the libs your project is depending on have to update their code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do about those warnings. If you look at the `package.json` files of those dependencies that you get the warning about, like [react-render-html](https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html/blob/master/package.json#L38), you'll see that they have React 15 as peer dependency.

The authors of these packages you are using will have to update their dependency to the latest React to fix those warnings.

You can, of course, fork the projects and create pull requests to make it easier for them.